# Mounting a monitor arms clamp on an IKEA desk, what can I use to distribute the load?

Tags: desk

I have [this IKEA desk](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/desks/desk-computer-desks/malm-desk-with-pull-out-panel-black-brown-art-60214183/) which I use for my computer. It currently holds two 27" monitors.

The monitors are too low for my eyesight, so I bought [this two-monitor arms](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B019LNW52C/) to hold them up and free some space underneath.

I was reading a bit about how strong the desk is, and it looks like the desk is likely too weak for the weight to be put on one 5cm x 5cm spot on the desk, due to the wooden panel's structure:

[image: desk panel]

So I need something to distribute the load across a larger surface of the desk. Probably something that's tough enough to actually distribute the load as opposed to something weak that will bend and just pass the load on the spot.

I'm not very experienced with DIY projects, any idea what I could use?

(I'm in London, UK, if it helps)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix puncture in Ikea Linmon table](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214880/fix-puncture-in-ikea-linmon-table)

Comment: @StayOnTarget TBH, A) that is about fixing a hole _after_ the mount has already caused damage, and B) _this_ question is a good reference for those who stop by periodically to ask how to do exactly this thing. To me, it makes a great dupe target and isn't a dupe itself.

Comment: @FreeMan It seems like there are (at least) 3 questions that are very similar. I picked the other as the dupe target because it had the most upvotes overall, but maybe there's some other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an edge mount. The edges of the table top will be solid wood. The honeycomb mesh is in the center. So there is no problem with clamping the mount there.

If still you don't trust it. You can use a strip of plywood or a bit of angle iron. Note that this will reduce the available depth of the clamp.

Answer (score 2):

I used two 7 by 7 inch piece of wood (1 top, 1 bottom ) and this works fine

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour] and browse through the [help], you'll see that we normally like longer, more complete answers. However, I've got to say that, in this situation, this really does seem to cover it! Please also note that the question you answered is nearly 3 years old, so, while very appropriate, it's a bit out of date.